# jQuery / JS: Random image with text? How to add the text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

I’ve downloaded a JavaScript which outputs a random image within an array. It all works great but I want to add a title variable, to put in both as the image alt text but also to display on the HTML page.

This is the JavaScript code I’m using:

```
(function($) {

    $.randomImage = {
        defaults: {

            path: 'images/',
            myImages: ['image01.png', 'image02.png', 'image03.png', 'image04.png ', 'image05.png ', 'image06.png ']

        }
    }

    $.fn.extend({
        randomImage: function(config) {

            var config = $.extend({}, $.randomImage.defaults, config);

            return this.each(function() {

                var imageNames = config.myImages;

                var imageNamesSize = imageNames.length;
                var lotteryNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageNamesSize);
                var winnerImage = imageNames[lotteryNumber];
                var fullPath = config.path + winnerImage;

                $(this).attr({
                    src: fullPath,
                    alt: winnerImage
                });

            });
        };
    });
})(jQuery);
```

How can I say that..
If random image03.png, then variable imageTitle = “This is an image of a horse” ???

And then in my HTML code, I can print out imageTitle.

Thank you
Sincere
- Mestika

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
(function($) {

    $.randomImage = {
        defaults: {

            path: 'http://static.php.net',
            myImages: [{
                src: '/www.php.net/images/php.gif',
                title: "This is a picture of a monkey"},
            {
                src: '/www.php.net/images/php.gif',
                title: "This is a picture of a squirrel"}
                                      ]
        }
    }

    $.fn.extend({
        randomImage: function(config) {
            var config = $.extend({}, $.randomImage.defaults, config);

            return this.each(function() {
                var imageNames = config.myImages;
                var imageNamesSize = imageNames.length;
                var lotteryNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageNamesSize);
                var winnerImage = imageNames[lotteryNumber].src;
                this.title = config.myImages[lotteryNumber].title;
                $(this).after("<p>" + this.title + "</p>");
                var fullPath = config.path + winnerImage;

                $(this).attr({
                    src: fullPath,
                    alt: winnerImage
                });
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);

$("#test").randomImage();
```

Test markup:

```
<img id="test"/>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C7hRT/1/

Answer (score 0):

Add another array

```
(function($) {

    $.randomImage = {
        defaults: {

            path: 'images/',
            myImages: ['image01.png', 'image02.png', 'image03.png', 'image04.png ', 'image05.png ', 'image06.png '],
            myTitles: ['t1','t2','t3','t4','t5','t6']

        }
    }

    $.fn.extend({
        randomImage: function(config) {

            var config = $.extend({}, $.randomImage.defaults, config);

            return this.each(function() {

                var imageNames = config.myImages;

                var imageNamesSize = imageNames.length;
                var lotteryNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageNamesSize);
                var winnerImage = imageNames[lotteryNumber];
                var titleText = config.myTitles[lotteryNumber];
                var fullPath = config.path + winnerImage;

                $(this).attr({
                    src: fullPath,
                    alt: titleText                                                
                });

            });
        };
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but can I ask one more question. How do I output the title on my HTML page? When outputting the image I use this code: <img class="shuffle" src="" alt="" id="image" title="">  but just can't get the title printed. I've another JS i load with this code: $('.shuffle').randomImage({path: 'images/'});

Answer (score 0):

You could add an "image chosen" callback easily enough.

First you need to change the format of `myImages` to include the image names:

```
myImages: [
    { img: 'image01.png', title: 'Pancakes' },
    { img: 'image02.png', title: 'More pancakes' },
    { img: 'image03.png', title: 'This is an image of a horse eating pancakes' },
    //...
]
```

Then you update this stuff:

```
var winnerImage = imageNames[lotteryNumber];
var fullPath = config.path + winnerImage;
$(this).attr({
    src: fullPath,
    alt: winnerImage
});
```

to pay attention to the new `myImages` format:

```
var winnerImage = imageNames[lotteryNumber];
var fullPath = config.path + winnerImage.img;
$(this).attr({
    src: fullPath,
    alt: winnerImage.title
});
```

Now you have a title and adding the callback can be done by adding this:

```
if(config.imageChosen)
    config.imageChosen(fullPath, winnerImage.title);
```

right after the `$(this).attr({` stuff.

Once that's in place, you send in the callback function when you call the plugin:

```
$(selector_of_your_choice).randomImage({
    myImages: [ /* The images as above */ ],
    imageChosen: function(imagePath, imageTitle) {
        /* Put the title, imageTitle, where ever you want it */
    }
});
```